# How to print or display DOMXPath object to see what it contains?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

I want to see what is inside a DOMXPath object. I am not referring to using query/evaluate functions of XPath. At the moment I have the following code:

```
$file = file_get_contents("schema.xsd");

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($file);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('xs', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
```

How do I display the $xpath using PHP?

Comment: What do you think the DOMXPath object might contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `print_r`, `var_dump` or `var_export` which allows you to "view" variables in PHP.

More information [in this link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

As a bonus, you can wrap it in a `pre` or `code` tag so it gets laid out decently.

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($xpath); ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: I forget if you have to `echo` or not.

Comment: Thanks. It gives the following DOMXPath Object ( [document] => (object value omitted) ). Is there any way to print the omitted object value?

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump` or `var_export`? I think one of them unravels the object. But I haven't done PHP in ages, so I'm not sure. Maybe DOMXPath is handled differently.

Comment: It doesn't make much of a difference. var_export gives "DOMXPath::__set_state(array( ))" and  var_dump gives "object(DOMXPath)#4 (1) { ["document"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" }"